# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ~ during @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have a create action and a edit action in a Reviews Controller.

My Create ActionLink is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { Id = Model.Id })
```

My create action is :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int Id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My Edit ActionLink is:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }
```

my edit is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var model = _db.Reviews.Find(id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

In my edit view, I have a Action Link called "Back to List" which is:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new {id = Model.RestaurantId}, null)
```

It works and takes me back to where I came from...

In my create view, when I put the same thing, I get error message that is in the heading. that Id does not have a value or is null.. So Model.RestaurantId does not have a value..

If I hard code a value ,it works such as:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Reviews", new { id = 1 }, null)
```

What could I be doing wrong...

I am essentially trying to follow Scott Allens MVC4 tutorial.
I am unable to understand why this is happening. I have a reviews controller. Can some one give me suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a viewmodel for your create view, with a property to store the source /parent id and use that as needed.

```
public classs CreateReviewVM
{
   public int SourceID { set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int Id)
{ 
   var vm=new CreateReviewVM { SourceID=id };
   return View(vm);
}
```

and your create view(`create.cshtml`) which is strongly typed to your `CreateReviewVM`

```
@model CreateReviewVM
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Reviews", 
                                              new { id = Model.SourceID }, null)
```

Comment: Ok...a view model. I will check on it and follow your suggestion and get back to you...But in the mean time, can you tell me why does my "Back to List" in Edit View works but not in the Create ? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can use:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id=Request.Params["restaurantId"] }, null)
```

and it will populate the value.